# Message: Undefined variable: core_settings Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, dompdf

I'm trying to use dompdf with codeigniter but after adding initial code i got an error

### error message

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: core_settings
>
> Filename: theme/application.php
>
> Line Number: 51

### this is the code in my controller

```
function pdf_create($html, $filename='', $stream=TRUE) 
{
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    if ($stream) {
        $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf");
    } else {
        return $dompdf->output();
    }
}

    function pdf()
{
     $this->load->helper(array('dompdf', 'file'));

     $html = '<h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>';
     pdf_create($html, 'filename');

}
```

### this is the line 51 in theme/application.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>assets/blueline/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=<?=$core_settings->version;?>" />
```

Comment: The error is self explanatory. the `$core_settings` variable here `ver=<?=$core_settings->version;?>` is undefined.

Comment: thank you for your answer ,, i wanted to know how to fix it,, i'm working on an existed project and i didn't work before with this framework.

Comment: for now you can remove the variable `$core_settings` and  see if anything breaks.